# Не удается подключиться к SQL Server удаленно, брандмауэр отключён

Tags: python, sql-server, сервер

Предпринимаю попытки подключиться к SQL Server. Экземпляр запущен, удаленные подключения разрешены, учетные данные добавлены, TCP разрешен для порта 1433, динамические порты тоже отключены. Использую pyodb для удаленного подключения

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
    'SERVER=ip,1433;'
    'DATABASE=dbname;'
    'UID=sa;'
    'PWD=pwd'
)
```

В результате получаю следующую ошибку:

Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.\r\n (10060) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Время ожидания входа в систему истекло (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]При установлении соединения с сервером SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и на сервере SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. Дополнительные сведения см. в электронной документации по SQL Server. (10060)')
Пожалуйста,помогите решить проблему, первый раз пытаюсь сделать клиент-сервер)

Comment: А разве пор через запятую а не двоеточие указывается?

Comment: попробовал, ошибка новая - недопустимая строка подключения

Comment: Уберите все `'` кроме начала и конца. Или используйте конкатенацию. Это должна быть 1 строка